# javascript iframe set timer and check if loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to trigger a url validation check onclick of the url before loading the page. If the url is not valid or cannot be reached I need to display an alert.

When I use i.onload it keeps waiting for it to load. If it never loads it also never produces an error to be caught by i.onerror. If the link loads properly everything works well.

html:

```
<a id={UrlToTest} onClick={this.testUrl}>{UrlToTest}</a>
```

javascript:

```
testURL(e) {
var targetURL = e.target.id;
var i = document.createElement('iframe');
i.style.display = 'none';
i.src = targetURL;
document.body.appendChild(i);
i.onload = function() {
//setTimeout(function(){
    i.parentNode.removeChild(i);
    return window.open(targetURL, '_blank');
 //}, 5000);
  };
  i.onerror = function(){
    alert('The link didn"t load');
  };
}
```

If I insert console.log's it remains waiting for onload to trigger. If I allow the link to open without testing in a hidden iframe it will display 'unable to connect' immediately, or 404 error, etc. This error is never received when checked within the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow :)

I believe your issue is that you set your onload and onerror after you set the src.

Think of it this way - your browser is trying to load (or error) the iframe as soon as possible, once the `src` is set, the browser starts his work, if an error (or success) is thrown before the `onload` was set, there's nothing to catch it.

TLDR - I think that switching the order (setting onload and onerror first) should resolve your problem.

Edit -- 
So I misunderstood the question, yes there are situations where nothing comes back from the iframe, specifically I could reproduce that with this code on the console here in stack overflow:

```
var targetURL = 'localhost:1'
var i = document.createElement('iframe');

i.onload = function() {
    alert('The link did load');
};
i.onerror = function(){
    alert('The link did NOT load');
};

i.src = targetURL;
document.body.appendChild(i);
```

the above code will not fire any event.
I'm not aware of why this is exactly happening, but maybe you should use a setTimeout timer to timeout the whole operation

```
let timer = setTimeout(() => {
    alert('Error opening page');
}, 5000);

var targetURL = 'localhost:1'
var i = document.createElement('iframe');

i.onload = function() {
    alert('The link did load');
    clearTimeout(timer);
};
i.onerror = function(){
    alert('The link did NOT load');
    clearTimeout(timer);
};

i.src = targetURL;
document.body.appendChild(i);
```

I dug a bit deeper, turns out there's a bug for Chrome on this matter

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=365457

Unfortunately it seems that 'this is the spec', from the bug report:

> I have discussed this with Adam Barth, and we have confirmed that the
>   behaviour described here is the behaviour described in the Living HTML
>   specification.
>
> As follows: The specification requires that all HTML elements support
>   on onerror event. However, it does NOT require that all elements
>   supporting network fetches raise fire a simple event called onerror.
>   That is, elements must support allowing applications to set error
>   handlers, but there is no (generic) requirement that the event be
>   raised, in either HTML or the Fetch specification.

Comment: This does not work either. Even with src set after onload and onerror, when there is an error it never hits within either the onload or onerror, yet if there is not an error it still triggers within onload.

Comment: I edited my answer - seems I misunderstood at first :) - you're right, it's an open bug and it looks like it's the expected behaviour (so the 'open bug' was rejected)

Comment: Thank you. I have adjusted mine to use a timer as suggested and if there is no response within a time limit display an error message. Do you have any suggestions as to how create a similar catch/test for Chrome? When I test in Chrome, onload always triggers, even when the site is not loadable or doesn't exist. But since they are cross domain I cannot check for an error response.

Comment: Hey Ariel, I noticed that as well - Loading a fake domain into an iframe will trigger the onload, which is very strange to say the least. if you expect to have access to the iframe (if it's your domain), you can try to probe it and see if you have access - if you do, it loaded, if you can't access it due to CORS, it means you failed to load it - hacky, but there's no way around it I think.